# What format does Redux Toolkit Query expect a response to be?

Tags: parsing, redux, react-redux, fetch-api, redux-toolkit

When I did the following:

```
import { useGetPostQuery } from "./store/postApi";
export function App() {
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, isError, error } = useGetPostQuery(1);
  if (isError)
    return (
      <div>
        {error.status}
        <br />
        {error.data}
      </div>
    );
  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>;
  return <div className={isFetching ? "posts--disabled" : ""}>{data}</div>;
}
```

I received an error:

PARSING_ERROR
HELLO WORLD

Basically, I just want to return the string HELLO WORLD from the server. How should I avoid the parsing error?

A [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-hooks-forked-1x5gxb?file=/src/App.js) for the example can be found here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it expects a JSON response.

My PHP script:

```
echo json_encode(array("data"=>file_get_contents("data".$_GET["id"].".txt")));
```